# bash: using function's exit code in conditional expressions

Tags: bash, function, exit-code

I have next code:

```
...
docker_test () {

        local masterip=$1
        nc -zv $masterip 2377
}
...
        until $(docker_test $masterip); do
           echo "First Master not initialized yet..."
           sleep 30
        done
...
```

The question is - is it correct approach in `bash` to use loops or `if/else` in a such way?

Another example could be:

```
if $(docker_test $masterip); then
    echo "Passed"
fi
```

Comment: What is the issue here, if your intention is run `nc -zv..` until it is successful (returning a code `0`) this looks fine

Comment: @Inian Thanks. Yes, it works. But I have doubts in exactly `until $(funcname); then` construction. Will be `until [ "$(docker_test $masterip)" == "0" ]` more correct way here? Or it can be safly simplified to the same code, as mine is?

Comment: @setevoy Do you want the standard output or the exit code of the function? If the latter, just drop the command substitution. `until docker_test "$master_ip"; do`. Otherwise, `until [ "$(docker_test "$master_ip")" = 0 ]` (`=`, not `==`) is correct.

Comment: @chepner Exit code, yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i wouldn't risk the chance of the script hanging indefinitely if there's a problem with master. i would do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

readonly TRIES = 5  # attempts before failing
readonly SLEEP = 30  # sleep in seconds

for try in $(seq 1 $TRIES); do
    if docker_test "$master_ip"; then
        echo "Passed"
        break
    else
        if [ $try -eq $TRIES ]; then
            echo "Failed"
            exit 1  # or whatever you need
        fi
        echo "Retrying. Try $try of $TRIES"
        sleep $SLEEP
    fi
done
```